# Facebook API call for places with limited results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to pull all the Facebook public events in my city through graph-API calls, to do that I believe that first I need to get all the places near by a point and then for each place get the events happening there. Is this correct?

Anyhow, when I try to get the places my API call returns only somewhere between 350 - 450 places depending on the center point. I know there are more than that.
My API call is:
/search?type=place&center=31.7570810,-106.4890170&distance=15000&limit=5000

Is there any limits for searching places Im not aware of?
Thanks in advance

Comment: place doesn't seem to be a valid Ad Targeting Search API value (documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search/v2.4) can you update your description with the official documentation you're using?